# Getting table primary key columns by query

Tags: c#, .net, sql, vb.net

```
SELECT [name]
FROM syscolumns 
 WHERE [id] IN (SELECT [id] 
                  FROM sysobjects 
                 WHERE [name] = 'ACTIVITY')
   AND colid IN (SELECT SIK.colid 
                   FROM sysindexkeys SIK 
                   JOIN sysobjects SO ON SIK.[id] = SO.[id]  
                    AND SO.[name] = 'ACTIVITY')
```

It is returning all the columns by id. I need only the primary key. When I add the following line it is empty:

```
                  WHERE SIK.indid = 1
```

Why is that? Is there other ways to do the same thing and working? Since I am in the rush

Comment: `indid = 1` would only give you information about the clustered index on the table, if it has one. There's no guarantee that the primary key and the clustered index are the same thing.

Answer (score 3):

Try this:

```
Declare @TableName varchar(128)

Set @TableName = 'YourTableName'

SELECT c.COLUMN_NAME as [PrimaryKeyColumns]

FROM    INFORMATION_SCHEMA.TABLE_CONSTRAINTS pk ,              
        INFORMATION_SCHEMA.KEY_COLUMN_USAGE c       
WHERE   pk.TABLE_NAME = @TableName      
AND     CONSTRAINT_TYPE = 'PRIMARY KEY'       
AND     c.TABLE_NAME = pk.TABLE_NAME       
AND     c.CONSTRAINT_NAME = pk.CONSTRAINT_NAME
```

Comment: This has been the only answer I've found that returns only the PK column name, and nothing else. If that sounds like your requirements, use this answer.

Answer (score 0):

This SQL will find all tables with primary keys:

```
SELECT 
    i.name AS IndexName,
    OBJECT_NAME(ic.OBJECT_ID) AS TableName,
    COL_NAME(ic.OBJECT_ID,ic.column_id) AS ColumnName
FROM 
    sys.indexes AS i
    INNER JOIN sys.index_columns AS ic
        ON i.OBJECT_ID = ic.OBJECT_ID
        AND i.index_id = ic.index_id
WHERE 
    i.is_primary_key = 1
```

I got it from [here](http://blog.sqlauthority.com/2007/09/04/sql-server-2005-find-tables-with-primary-key-constraint-in-database/). There are some other examples [here](http://www.mssqltips.com/tip.asp?tip=1237).

Answer (score 0):

This is the SQL that I use to return the primary key(s) for a table in SQL Server.

```
DECLARE @TableSchema varchar(255)
SET @TableSchema = 'dbo'
SET @TableName = 'table_name_here'

SELECT 
    ColumnName = col.column_name
FROM    
    information_schema.table_constraints tc               
    INNER JOIN information_schema.key_column_usage col
        ON col.Constraint_Name = tc.Constraint_Name
        AND col.Constraint_schema = tc.Constraint_schema    
WHERE 
    tc.Constraint_Type = 'Primary Key'
    AND col.Table_name = @TableName
    AND col.Table_Schema = @TableSchema
```